MobileSDK: Implement code obfuscation?
Any experience / recommended tool for obfuscating the following code?
Android:
com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui LoginActivity.java
iOS:
SFLoginViewController.m
I have been asked to do so, but starting the obfuscation leads to a string of dependency errors.
